# Solving a diffusion problem

Tags: heat-equation

I have to the following diffusion problem , which is given by the one-dimensional diffusion equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f=\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{d}{dt}f
\end{equation}

It is given that the diffusion constant is $1/4$, so I take that is $a$. So we have to solve:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f=16\frac{d}{dt}f
\end{equation}

The initial conditions are

\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=
\begin{cases}
2 \ \ \ 0\leq x\leq1\\
0 \ \ \ x>1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I assume that since this is a time-dependent problem, the solution must be a function in the form $f(x,t)$. So f can be represented as $f=\Psi(x)T(t)$, and we can obtain the solution by separation of variables. This gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
s16f_{xx}=f_t\\
16\Psi_{xx}T=T_t\Psi \\
16\frac{\Psi_{xx}}{\Psi}=\frac{T_t}{T} \\
16\frac{\Psi_{xx}}{\Psi}=\frac{T_t}{T}=k^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Giving the two ODEs:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
a16\Psi_{xx}-k^2\Psi=0\\
T_t-k^2T=0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The former is solved by the characteristic determinant:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
16\Psi_{xx}-k^2\Psi=0\\
m=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{-4\cdot(-\frac{k^2}{16}}\\
\Psi(x)=Ae^{kx/4}+Be^{-kx/4}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since the I.C. shows  existence at the origin of the solution, then the cosine terms vanish, and we have:

\begin{equation}
\Psi(x)=A\sin{kx/4}
\end{equation}

The second equation is solved by

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
l T_t-k^2T=0\\
\frac{1}{t}dT=k^2dt\\
T(t)=Ce^{k^2t}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Combining the two in one form, $f=\Psi T$:

\begin{equation}
f(x,t)=A\sin(k/4x)e^{k^2t}
\end{equation}

But when I apply the IC I run into a problem:

For $0\leq x\leq 1$, where $f(x,0)=0$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
1 A\sin(kx/4)e^{0}=0\\
k=\frac{4n\pi}{x} \rightarrow \\
f(x,t)=A\sin(n\pi)e^{k^2t}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

So there is no  $x$variable anymore. And with the second IC, A=0. So this has not worked. What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It is wrong to assume that the solution can be represented as $f=\Psi(x)T(t).$ Hint : google the fundamental solution of the heat equation also know as heat kernel.

Comment: @KurtG. Haven't found much so far, but I have the impression one can use Laplace transform, since we have ICs. Do I still separate the t-part and the x-part from one another?

Comment: @KurtG.  Actually it is not wrong to do this assumption, see page 4 in https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwix0_qR1e32AhUCixoKHbS3AT4QFnoECAoQAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Framanujan.math.trinity.edu%2Frdaileda%2Fteach%2Fs17%2Fm3357%2Flectures%2Flecture9.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2crR5Ko8X1E8fdRqJj6_Dy

Comment: Try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309586/solving-the-heat-equation-using-the-separation-of-variables?rq=1).

Comment: Looks good thanks. .